# can we concate (byte *) to (int) in c++?

Tags: python, c++, reverse-engineering, ghidra

I decompiled a .so file in ghidra and I found a line of code :

```cpp
puVar24 = (ulong *)(pbVar12 + 0x10);
```

pbVar12 type : byte *

0x10 type    : int

so if we can concate byte* with int how in python ?

Comment: What does “concatenate” mean; do you mean *added*? (Numbers can’t be “concatenated” in Python either; nor does Python have a byte* type..)

Comment: i mean '+' in code  ( puVar24 = (ulong *)(pbVar12 + 0x10); )

Comment: That's address arithmetic.  It says "take the address 16 bytes from pbVar12 and store it in puVar24".  Since Python doesn't have pointers, there's no way to convert this to Python code.

Comment: @TimRoberts Oh thanks ! so we can't implement this in python ?

Comment: I am noob in c++ , sorry !

Comment: Depends on what “this” means. While Python lacks the notion of C pointers (so it isn’t generally convertible), there are modules that allow dealing with binary data in “C-like ways” (one method https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html).

Comment: You can't implement that instruction.  In general, converting C to Python is tricky, because C applications tend to work with raw memory and manipulate pointers, which don't exist in Python.  You need to figure out what the code does, and not look at each statement.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a C++ issue but a very down-to-earth C feature: pointer arithmetic. `pbVar12` is not a `byte` or `char` or anything. The `*` very much indicates that it's a *pointer* to `byte`. Sometimes, pointers are *really* confusing:

1. `pbVar12` is an address in memory: if you imagine memory as a long street, then every cell in memory corresponds to a house and each house has house numbers. And `pbVar12` stores this number.
2. Pointers allow something kind-of unexpected in C: you can add numbers to them. So if `pbVar12` is, say `0x1337` and you add `0x10`, the result will be `0x1347`. Within the metaphor: you start with house number `0x1337` and progress `0x10` houses "up the street" ending up at house `0x1347`.
3. I didn't lie in the previous point but I left out a detail that only matters in a more general situation: when you add a number `x` to a pointer `p`, the result is not just `p` plus `x` but `p` plus `x` multiplied by the size of the *referenced data type*. And the referenced data type here is `byte`, which has a size of `1`, so this detail doesn't matter. If `pbVar12` wouldn't be a pointer to `byte` but to, say `float`, the result would be `0x1377` instead because `float` has a size of `4` (`0x1337 + 0x10 * 4 = 0x1377`) . Stretching the metaphor a bit now I suppose, but you can imagine in this general case, tha the pointer points not to a street of single houses but to street of building complexes, where each complex is so big, it has multiple house numbers (4 in this case). And "progressing one house" actually means skipping 4 house numbers.

Now that we got the low-level details straight, I'll give a bit more context and an explanation in the reversing context: These kinds of pointers-arithmetics is used by C internally when working with arrays. The notation `a[i]` is actually just syntactic sugar for `*(a + i)` (which reads as "add `i` to the pointer `a` and dereference the result).

So if I would have to guess, I'd assume that `pbVar12` actually is an array of `unsinged long` and the `+ 0x10` actually means indexing it at position 4 (`0x10 = 16 = 4 * 4`). Or to phrase this in a short C-snipped:

```c
unsigned long *puVar24;
unsigned long pbVar12[123];
puVar24 = &pbVar12[4];
```

You also mentioned Python, so I'll loose a few more words about that: I assume you are trying to re-implement some code you saw in Ghidra in Python, maybe because you want to emulate some behavior. The confusion now is that you don't actually work with data directly and numbers but with references to memory addresses. So you actually would need to understand, how `puVar24` is used later and need to read the corresponding 4 bytes of memory located at `pbVar12 + 4` (or `pbVar12 + 16` if `pbVar12` really turns out to be a `byte` array as opposed to a `float` array).

Comment: it's a structure for sure . so all this `unsigned long *puVar24;` is plain wrong